# Open and close modal windows not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What am trying to do is when a user clicks the ".inner" element it finds the modal window that is inside of it and removes the "slideOutLeft" class if there is one and then adds the "slideInLeft" class and fades in the overlay element. **This works fine**.

But what **doesn't** work is when you click the .closeBtn element it doesn't remove the "slideInLeft" and then add the "slideOutLeft" class. But when you click the *black overlay* behind the modal window it **does** function properly.

I'm obviously missing something but I can't figure it out.

[Here is a fiddle with all my code](https://jsfiddle.net/ssjfu611/17/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.inner').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.modalWindow').removeClass('slideOutLeft').addClass('slideInLeft').css('display', 'block');
    $('.overlay').fadeToggle(500);
  });

  $('.closeBtn, .overlay').click(function() {
    $('.modalWindow').removeClass('slideInLeft').addClass('slideOutLeft');
    $('.overlay').fadeToggle(500);
  });

});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
.modalBtn {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999997;
  display: none;
}
.modalWindow {
  width: 80%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 999998;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}
.closeBtn {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 5px;
}
.inner:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Animations */

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
/*the animation definition*/

@-webkit-keyframes slideInLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
  }
}
@keyframes slideInLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-125%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-125%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-125%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
  }
}
.slideInLeft {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInLeft;
  animation-name: slideInLeft
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideOutLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)
  }
}
@keyframes slideOutLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-125%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-125%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-125%, 0, 0)
  }
}
.slideOutLeft {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideOutLeft;
  animation-name: slideOutLeft
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">

    <div class="modalBtn">click for modal 1</div>

    <div class="modalWindow animated">
      <div class="closeBtn">X</div>
      <span>This is modal window 1</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">

    <div class="modalBtn">click for modal 2</div>

    <div class="modalWindow animated">
      <div class="closeBtn">X</div>
      <span>This is modal window 2</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a snippet for you. Your JSFiddle was wrong too. No jQuery selected and running onload instead of in head: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/y1zbz318/

Comment: @kodecount create an answer and I will accept that as correct cause you are right seeing as the modal windows was inside of the "inner" element it was still clickable. You answer actually took care of that.

Comment: @agon024 Posted my comment as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `<div class="inner">` is still clickable please change your HTML mark up:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="modalBtn">click for modal 1</div>
  </div>

  //KEEP THIS OUT OF THE INNER DIV
  <div class="modalWindow animated">
    <div class="closeBtn">X</div>
    <span>This is modal window 1</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then your JavaScript too:

```
$('.inner').click(function() {
 $(this).parent().find('.modalWindow').removeClass('slideOutLeft').addClass('slideInLeft').css('display', 'block');
 $('.overlay').fadeToggle(500);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this as this would have caused me problems later.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is in your html structure, so when you click on close button you are clicking on .inner div, too:
Fix:

```
 $('.closeBtn, .overlay').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
    $('.modalWindow').removeClass('slideInLeft').addClass('slideOutLeft');
    $('.overlay').fadeToggle(500);
  });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ssjfu611/24/

Comment: This is breakable. The `<div class="inner">` is still clickable and you can cause the modal overlay to appear with no modal. Click where the button is located under the overlay (double click a couple of times).

Comment: @kodecount, i didn't pay atention to that problem from original question/fiddle. My answer was related to mentioned problem in original post/question, and it is not cause of behavior you've described. Anyway, HTML re-structuring is probably better (safer) option.

Comment: Understandable. Just didn't want to see the user implement this and have to fix it eventually on their application.